# Prevent highly upvoted topic or example from being removed

Tags: discussion, feature-request, documentation, documentation-proposals

Currently, topics or examples removal seems to be quite easy. Many highly upvoted topics or examples are removed easily.

---

Personally, I think that the Docs review queue isn't really effective. 100 rep to review proposed changes is very low. Even edit questions and answers  privilege requires 2,000 reputation.

**That's 100 vs 2000!!!**

---

Today, my reputation was decreased by around 170 and it's the 3rd time that my reputation has drastically decreased due to Docs deletion. However, I can't seem to find the example that was deleted. It really isn't fair to the contributor if the example is deleted without any discussion.

---

### So,

1. The reputation required to approve Documentation changes should be set higher. (maybe at 500 or 1000)
2. There should be a safeguard to prevent highly upvoted example to be deleted.
3. The deleted example that caused the rep loss should be made easier to find for the contributor. (maybe through the Reputation tab in Profile)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I already finished this quest. Here's a trivial solution to your problem.

1. Go to your reputation tab;
2. Switch to post mode;
3. Check "show removed posts";
4. Expand every day;
5. Find a day with a big reputation loss;
6. Go to the removed example;
7. The website will say it's removed;
8. Go to the topic history;
9. If the change that removed the example is the last one, good luck! Revert to the previous version. **Done.**
10. Otherwise, search for the change that removed the topic by viewing every change one by one;
11. Go to the last topic edit with the example (topic mode, not diff mode!);
12. Scroll to the example, go to the example's change history;
13. Find the last edit with the correct state of the example;
14. Go to the the edit (topic mode, not diff mode!);
15. Scroll to the example;
16. Now you can rollback just this example;
17. Submit your change to review queue;
18. The example is back. **Done.**

I have no idea why you received so many downvotes. The reasoning is questionable, I agree, as upvotes aren't a perfect indicator of quality, but removing a good example is too easy. I got my highly upvoted example removed because one user chose incorrect reason when submitting an improvement request (the comment was sensible though), some low-level user decided to click the suggested "Delete" button, and several robo-reviewers with zero experience in the topic approved the removal.

It's a part of the bigger problem, which is access of newbies with zero experience to the review queue.

Comment: Thanks :) Interesting workaround and great answer!

Comment: Just as a side not if you see an example of a really bad review you may want to mod flag so the mods can take a look and issue review bans if needed.